# SAS: I need help to calculate variable's value based on the previous value in the same variable

Tags: sas

I have excel table and my goal is to convert this table to SAS.

The table has almost 100 columns with different statistic formula in each column, when some formulas depend on other columns.

This is the small sample of the table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Random number | Year | Normal Gross return | Gross Fund | Gross IRR |
| 6 |  | 0 |  |  |  |
| 7 | 1.294000103 | 1 | 18.13% | 76.96 | -18.13% |
| 8 | -0.330857931 | 2 | 25.50% | 214.55 | 9.14% |
| 9 | -0.003978838 | 3 | 8.55% | 334.92 | 8.85% |
| 10 | -0.130874637 | 4 | -6.42% | 401.40 | 2.63% |
| 11 | -0.508842621 | 5 | 9.07% | 540.35 | 4.69% |

The excel formula to calculate column D (Gross Fund) is:

```
Cell(D7)=D6*(1+C7)+Premium*(1-expenseload)*(1+C7)
```

Niotice, that in this column I have to take value from previous row.
"Premium" and "ExpenceLoad" are named ranges in excel.
I saw previous topics about Lag function and tried different approaches to solve the problem, but nothing gone well and I don't get the correct result.
The current SAS code in my program (Within Data step) is:

```
GrossFund = Lag(GrossFund)*(1+NGrossReturn)+&GrossAnnualPremium*(1-&ExpenceLoad)*(1+NGrossReturn);
```

It returns Nulls only.

Here is SAS code that build example of the DataSet I'm working on.
To notice that the full set has:
6 Tranches (From 1 To 6),
Each tranche contains 15000 Iterations (From 1 to 15000),
Each Iteration contains 42 years (From 0 to 41) Where Rows with Year=0 must
be blank or zero values.

```
%let Stdev_base = 0.187493224932249;
%let weight_to_equities = 0.5;
%let Stdev_ToUse = &Stdev_base*&weight_to_equities;
%let Term_Interval = 1;
%let GrossAnnualPremium = 100;
%let ExpenceLoad = 0.06; 

Data Test;
Infile datalines dlm="09"x dsd;
Input Tranche Iteration Year NormInv  NetReturn Tresv NGrossReturn;
datalines;
1   1   0   0           0
1   1   1   -0.401683176    -0.192583212    16  -0.181279377
1   1   2   -2.188102767    0.237673136 16  0.25500056
1   1   3   -1.082351454    0.070470576 16  0.085457165
1   1   4   0.502844303 -0.077089014    16  -0.06416826
1   1   5   -0.764272142    0.075668747 16  0.09072811
1   1   6   0.832236652 0.080999439 16  0.096133431
1   1   7   -0.248428708    0.037800642 16  0.052329851
1   1   8   -0.696929109    0.012473564 16  0.026648194
1   1   9   -0.177708172    0.022553857 16  0.036869611
1   1   10  0.361635108 0.060861948 16  0.075714016
1   1   11  0.968456872 -0.03329219 16  -0.019758281
1   1   12  0.507503347 0.100902401 16  0.116315034
1   1   13  0.094918729 0.044654956 16  0.059280125
1   1   14  -0.268100788    0.100029068 16  0.115429475
1   1   15  1.114988618 -0.095820118    16  -0.0831616
1   1   16  0.621812038 0.020710059 16  0.035
1   1   17  -0.240327682            -0.03444714
1   1   18  -0.518506761            -0.05930167
1   1   19  -0.380628296            -0.047063621
1   1   20  0.216490394         0.007800988
1   1   21  -0.865064972            -0.08937257
1   1   22  0.516558723         0.036553334
1   1   23  0.635065672         0.048133258
1   1   24  0.614818545         0.046145683
1   1   25  1.703085114         0.15850912
1   1   26  0.306297412         0.016321587
1   1   27  1.054664304         0.090184211
1   1   28  -0.927067255            -0.094650243
1   1   29  -0.378329899            -0.046858273
1   1   30  1.37836213          0.123773543
1   1   31  0.698802551         0.054414724
1   1   32  1.877871249         0.177648372
1   1   33  -1.801178849            -0.165880781
1   1   34  -2.301837034            -0.204125642
1   1   35  -0.064140869            -0.01836675
1   1   36  -0.011118909            -0.013475268
1   1   37  0.16684725          0.003121704
1   1   38  -0.907010833            -0.092946383
1   1   39  -0.5522686          -0.062274328
1   1   40  -0.926762702            -0.094624394
1   1   41  -0.49304509         -0.057053593
1   2   0   0           0
1   2   1   0.272052109 -0.192583212    16  -0.181279377
1   2   2   -1.281898069    0.237673136 16  0.25500056
1   2   3   -0.647768883    0.070470576 16  0.085457165
1   2   4   -0.565498028    -0.077089014    16  -0.06416826
1   2   5   0.41197637  0.075668747 16  0.09072811
1   2   6   -0.779413048    0.080999439 16  0.096133431
1   2   7   0.855643268 0.037800642 16  0.052329851
1   2   8   -0.866463325    0.012473564 16  0.026648194
1   2   9   1.07588221  0.022553857 16  0.036869611
1   2   10  0.163612115 0.060861948 16  0.075714016
1   2   11  -0.033478564    -0.03329219 16  -0.019758281
1   2   12  -0.260679455    0.100902401 16  0.116315034
1   2   13  1.02590182  0.044654956 16  0.059280125
1   2   14  -2.021439569    0.100029068 16  0.115429475
1   2   15  -0.266694607    -0.095820118    16  -0.0831616
1   2   16  1.394018033 0.020710059 16  0.035
1   2   17  -0.042766779            -0.016397831
1   2   18  0.224547946         0.008562537
1   2   19  -2.84164275         -0.243398743
1   2   20  -0.529668341            -0.060285465
1   2   21  1.249656009         0.110295831
1   2   22  -0.032835878            -0.015481683
1   2   23  -0.336196189            -0.04308602
1   2   24  0.321693245         0.01778951
1   2   25  0.664098464         0.050989875
1   2   26  -0.969997516            -0.098286561
1   2   27  1.234485887         0.108717949
1   2   28  -0.371113375            -0.046213231
1   2   29  -0.217901648            -0.03241506
1   2   30  -0.487483006            -0.056561787
1   2   31  -0.462498733            -0.054349485
1   2   32  -0.425287629            -0.051044903
1   2   33  1.539378448         0.140865279
1   2   34  -0.458411447            -0.053987072
1   2   35  0.871198126         0.071594097
1   2   36  1.278369561         0.11328855
1   2   37  -0.232312352            -0.033721341
1   2   38  0.435834918         0.028738736
1   2   39  1.057741102         0.090498708
1   2   40  0.987034372         0.083294223
1   2   41  0.249422192         0.010917124
1   3   0   0           0
1   3   1   -0.24711478 -0.192583212    16  -0.181279377
1   3   2   0.193853784 0.237673136 16  0.25500056
1   3   3   0.722182005 0.070470576 16  0.085457165
1   3   4   -0.524994456    -0.077089014    16  -0.06416826
1   3   5   0.597940421 0.075668747 16  0.09072811
1   3   6   1.822602911 0.080999439 16  0.096133431
1   3   7   -0.66550602 0.037800642 16  0.052329851
1   3   8   0.229251942 0.012473564 16  0.026648194
1   3   9   0.515539259 0.022553857 16  0.036869611
1   3   10  -0.464778008    0.060861948 16  0.075714016
1   3   11  -2.071355087    -0.03329219 16  -0.019758281
1   3   12  -0.290791577    0.100902401 16  0.116315034
1   3   13  -0.092066762    0.044654956 16  0.059280125
1   3   14  0.564862272 0.100029068 16  0.115429475
1   3   15  -0.251988426    -0.095820118    16  -0.0831616
;
run;
```

I need help to find the simplest solution to make the calculation with less steps as possible, because, as I noticed, i need to calculate almost a hundred additional variables. and i don't want the code to be to complicated and unreadable.

Expected result only for first 15 rows (only in these rows, for each iteration, the result is constant. Starting from row 16 the results is different for every row cause it based on random number in formula), i.e. if the result in first 15 row is similar to the table i can suppose that further results is also OK:

| Random number | Year | Normal Gross return | Gross Fund |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.049364577 | 1 | -18.13% | 76.96 |
| 0.560315127 | 2 | 25.50% | 214.55 |
| 0.502450342 | 3 | 8.55% | 334.92 |
| -0.061151989 | 4 | -6.42% | 401.40 |
| 1.640308957 | 5 | 9.07% | 540.35 |
| 0.345543548 | 6 | 9.61% | 695.33 |
| -0.953935106 | 7 | 5.23% | 830.63 |
| 0.53277643 | 8 | 2.66% | 949.27 |
| -0.956756512 | 9 | 3.69% | 1081.74 |
| 0.598816648 | 10 | 7.57% | 1264.76 |
| -0.321960944 | 11 | -1.98% | 1331.91 |
| 1.057035832 | 12 | 11.63% | 1591.77 |
| 0.087963633 | 13 | 5.93% | 1785.70 |
| -1.423907034 | 14 | 11.54% | 2096.67 |
| 0.450617369 | 15 | -8.32% | 2008.49 |
| -0.085762382 | 16 | 3.50% | 2176.08 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the actual input?  That is which of the cells actual have DATA and which are just FORMULAS?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a SAS DATA step with a small amount of sample data (CARDS statement), and the SAS code you have tried that is giving incorrect results?

Comment: Your excel formula does not match your data listing.  D6 is an empty cell so your calculation of D7 is going to fail.

Comment: I added the SAS code to give you example of data set.

Comment: Can you add the expected computed result for the `grossfund ` to the sample data.

Comment: Updated. Added the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple calculations involving 100's of variables will likely be neither uncomplicated nor readable.  If there is a pattern to the calculations, you might be able to simplify the pattern using arrays.

Because your initial `Lag(GrossFund)` is a missing value, you probably want to use `coalesce`

```
  GrossFund = 
    coalesce(Lag(GrossFund),0)             * (1+NGrossReturn)
  + &GrossAnnualPremium * (1-&ExpenceLoad) * (1+NGrossReturn)
  ;
```

Comment: Hi, with coalesce addition it does returns values, but they are different from what they must be, i.e. the result calculation is wrong.